# Microsoft Dynamics GP 10.0: Where is the "business object"/stored procedure documentation?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, accounting, dynamics-gp, econnect

I've been looking at, among other things, the "eConnect Programmer's Guide Release 10.0" for Microsoft Dynamics GP.

There are stored procedures (termed "Business Objects") referred to in this document that I can call to get/modify data in the Dynamics database....but curiously, the document doesn't actually tell me the names of them, what their parameters are, or what they do.

I've been poking around various places online and haven't been able to locate this documentation.  Can anyone help?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the business objects is contained in the Software Development Kit (SDK) for Microsoft Dynamics GP 10. You can download it from Customer Source or Partner Source.